# Asp.net MVC route mapping query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

The default route map specified in MVC is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

This will allow a URL like http://mysite.com/controller/action/id

Having read other posts on stackoverflow, I had the impression (incorrectly) that to add SEO information to my MVC urls I could simply change the route map to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{seo}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, seo = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Which would allow a URL like http://mysite.com/controller/action/id/information-for-search-engines

It DOES in fact route correctly, but for some reason it now calls the action THREE TIMES?? Is there something basic I have done wrong here?

Comment: You sure it's the routing calling it 3 times? You don't have multiple `Html.Action`'s?

Comment: I'm with Liam. What your describing is not technically possible. MVC Routes use short-circuit logic. Once it finds a matching route, it calls the associated action and exits. It won't match three times.

Comment: Yeah, its definitely calling it three times - the URL Im trying it with is just a simple http://whatever/controller/action/id/something - Im new to MVC routing so I will try look deeper into it.

Comment: @Jimbo I agree with Chris. Are you using something like Firebug while calling the route? I experienced a similar behavior while using Firebug, I don't know the reason, but everything works fine when it is turned off.